# Colorizing old school VI

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

I'm working in a old environment, installing VIM is not an option and neither other similar packages. My only editor available is the old school VI, version 3.10. So, I wanted to ask you guys, do you folks think there is a way for me to set syntax color on it? (Like, e.g., adding source code from `:syntax on` to the `.exrc` file)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As I understand, POSIX vi has no syntax highlighting. Version 5 of Vim was the first Vim version to (officially) introduce syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"old school VI" version 3.10 sounds like AIX (good luck on finding "vim 3.10").

For the record, I see these  reported by AIX (for the ":ve" command):

```
Version 3.10
```

HPUX 11.23:

```
HP Version $ B.11.23  Dec  2 2004 03:59:23 $
```

Solaris 10:

```
Version SVR4.0, Solaris 2.5.0
```

AIX vi (like all of the other "old school VI") predates [POSIX vi](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/vi.html), and none of those supported color syntax highlighting.  You can see what options are runtime-configurable using ":set all".  For AIX:

```
:set all
noautoindent            mesg                            noshowmode
autoprint               nomodeline                      noslowopen
noautowrite             nonumber                        tabstop=8
nobeautify              nonovice                        taglength=0
closepunct='".,;)]}     nooptimize                      tags=tags /usr/lib/tags
directory=/var/tmp      paragraphs=IPLPPPQPP LIpplpipbp backtag
noedcompatible          partialcharacter=-              term=vt100
noerrorbells            prompt                          noterse
noexrc                  noreadonly                      timeout
flash                   redraw                          ttytype=vt100
hardtabs=8              remap                           warn
history=32              report=5                        window=39
noignorecase            scroll=19                       wrapscan
linelimit=1048560       sections=NHSHH HUuhsh+c         wrapmargin=0
nolisp                  shell=/opt/fsw/bin/zsh          nowriteany
nolist                  shiftwidth=8                    wraptype=word
magic                   noshowmatch
```

There's no "color" or "syntax" there.

SVr4 came in late 1988 (and subsequent releases through the early 1990s).

The first *nix-based vi's which could do color highlighting began with Elvis in 1994, followed by vile in 1995 and vim in 1998 (see [FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html#clone_colors)).  More general syntax highlighting followed in each case about a year later.